# Grafana build from source error (go-sqlite)

Tags: go, grafana, go-sqlite3

I am trying to build grafana from source for Win-32 bit version according to the following [grafana instructions](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/contribute/developer-guide.md). I am currently using golang 1.14 (instead of 1.20) as i had had previously several problems according to the [following post](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/grafana-error-build-from-source/32489/9)  and now i am having the following error regarding go-sqlite version.

[image]

For your better convenience, i send you the link to my [go.mod file](https://rb.gy/9q2ug).

Regards

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)